# Using a cutsom TableCellRenderer to change the background of a cell

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a table that has three columns of strings. I want the last column to have a green background and a bold font. So I figure I need a custom TableCellRenderer. But when I call `table.setDefaultRenderer` it looks for a `Class columnClass` along with an instance of my custom renderer. So I gave it the value `String.class`. But it does not get used for rendering, I have set a breakpoint in it's getTableCellRendererComponent method and it isn't hit.

Here's the code where I set the custom renderer -

```
public class TableTest extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    MyTableCellRenderer renderer = new MyTableCellRenderer();
    MyTableModel model = new MyTableModel();
    JTable table = new JTable();


    public TableTest() {
        super(new GridLayout(1,0));

        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 800));

        model.addRow(Arrays.asList("Testing", "Hello world", "Goodbye"));
        model.addRow(Arrays.asList("Testing", "Hello world", "Goodbye"));
        table = new JTable(model);
        table.setDefaultRenderer(String.class, new MyTableCellRenderer());
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(500, 70));
        table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);

        //Create the scroll pane and add the table to it.
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);

        //Add the scroll pane to this panel.
        add(scrollPane);
    }
}



public class MyTableCellRenderer extends JLabel implements TableCellRenderer {

    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {

        this.setText(value.toString());
        setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        setText("Test");
        return this;
}   

public class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

    private List<String> columnNames = new ArrayList<String>();

    private List<List> data = new ArrayList();

    {
        columnNames.add("Test");
        columnNames.add("Test");
        columnNames.add("Test");
    }

    public void addRow(List<String> rowData) {
        data.add(rowData);
        fireTableRowsInserted(data.size() - 1, data.size() - 1);
    }

    public int getRowCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    public int getColumnCount() {
        return columnNames.size();
    }

    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        return data.get(rowIndex).get(columnIndex);
    }

}
```

What am I doing wrong, why doesnt the cell renderer get used?

**Note: I have edited the post to include the other classes.**

Comment: please where is code for your Renderer

Comment: I think it would be handy to include the code for MyTableCellRenderer too. And does your MyTableModel implement `getColumnClass`? If so, debug it to discover what class it's returning.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Hi guys I have included the other classes now.

Answer (score 3):

Check your `TableModel.getColumnClass(int col)`, maybe it returns `Object.class`. Then you need to register the renderer with `Object.class` instead of `String.class`, ie:

```
table.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new MyTableCellRenderer());
```

Comment: The logical step would be to adjust your table model to return String.class for the getColumnClass method instead of registering the renderer for Object.class

Answer (score 3):

maybe there you can find out how use the [Renderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender) for [JTable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html), examples
[here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/Table-Renderer-Editor.htm), or [here](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/javax.swing.table/pkg.html), or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java+swing+jtable+renderer)

Answer (score 2):

> I want the last column to have a green background and a bold font.

If you just want the custom rendering on the last column, instead of calling `table.setDefaultRenderer()`, you could use this instead (assuming you have a fixed number of columns in the table):

```
table.getColumnModel().getColumn(table.getColumnCount()-1).setCellRenderer(new MyTableCellRenderer());
```

Answer (score 1):

I see you have your own `MyTableModel`. Have you overloaded `getColumnClass()` in your model? Then you can specify that the first column contains Strings and the table should then use the renderer you set for Strings.

Comment: (and @Max) the column class often is the culprit, but not a problem in the OPs requirement :-)